# Exibir dados JSON em carrossel (scroll infinito JavaScript)

Tags: php, javascript, json, codeigniter

Fiz um scroll infinito em JS, ou seja, toda vez que a pagina chega ao final é feita uma requisição GET para uma página do próprio site que retorna filmes de um gênero em JSON porém, ao ele rolar novamente os novos filmes devem ser colocados em outros carrosséis. Segue abaixo os códigos que fiz(codeigniter 3):
Dados retornados pela "API":

```
[
{
"slug": "2018ej982je",
"img": "roxo.png",
"nome": "8",
"descricao": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.",
"duracao": "02:11",
"classificacao": "1",
"ano": "2000",
"genero": "Ação"
},
{
"slug": "2018ej982je",
"img": "roxo.png",
"nome": "5",
"descricao": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.",
"duracao": "02:11",
"classificacao": "1",
"ano": "2000",
"genero": "Ação"
},
```

Este é um trecho do código que exibe um carrossel corretamente, porém esse aqui é so para entendimnento

```
if(isset($filmes_familia)){ ?>
    <div class="container-fluid mt-5" style="margin-bottom: 50px !important;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="ne_busness_main_slider_wrapper">
                    <div class="ne_recent_heading_main_wrapper">
                        <h2 style="color: white; font-weight: bold; margin-left: 15px;">Filmes para toda família</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid filme ">
        <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme home-slider nav-outer show-nav-hover nav-image-center filmes_familia" data-owl-options="{
            'loop': false,
            'autoHeight': true,
            'dots': false,
            'nav': false,
            'margin': 15,
            'autoplay': false,
            'responsive': {
                '1080': {
                    'items': 5  
                },
                '640': {
                    'items': 3  
                },
                '480': {
                    'items': 2  
                }
            }
        }
        ">
        
        <?php foreach($filmes_familia as $filme){ ?>
            <div class="list-item">
                <div class="film-list">
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url('perfil/watch?code='.$filme->filme_slug); ?>">
                        <figure class="zoom">
                            <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/imagens/filmes/mini/'.$filme->filme_imagem_principal); ?>" alt="<?php echo $filme->filme_nome; ?>" style="width: 100%;">
                        </figure>
                    </a>
                    <div class="actions">
                        <div class="title">
                            <h5 class="text-white"><?php echo $filme->filme_nome; ?></h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="actions-list">
                            <div class="row">
                                <ul>
                                    <div class="col play"><li><a href="<?php echo base_url('perfil/watch?code='.$filme->filme_slug); ?>" data-title="Assistir" class="title-tip"><i class="icon fas fa-play-circle"></i></a></li></div>
                                    <div class="col plus"><li><a href="<?php echo base_url('perfil/mylist/'.($this->Core_model->get_by_id('minha_lista', array('minha_lista_perfil_id' => $perfil->perfil_id, 'minha_lista_slug' => $filme->filme_slug)) ? 'del' : 'add').'/'.$filme->filme_slug); ?>" data-title="Adicionar a minha lista" class="title-tip"><i class="icon fas fa-plus"></i></a></li></div>
                                    <div class="col thumbs-up"><li><a href="<?php echo base_url('perfil/home/like_add/'.$filme->filme_slug); ?>" data-title="Gostei deste filme" class="title-tip"><i class="icon fas fa-thumbs-up"></i></a></li></div>
                                    <div class="col thumbs-down"><li><a href="<?php echo base_url('perfil/home/deslike_add/'.$filme->filme_slug); ?>" data-title="Não gostei deste filme" class="title-tip"><i class="icon fas fa-thumbs-down"></i></a></li></div>
                                    <div class="col info-circle"><li><a href="<?php echo base_url('perfil/detalhes?code='.$filme->filme_slug); ?>" data-title="Mais Detalhes" class="title-tip"><i class="icon fas fa-info-circle"></i></a></li></div>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="descr">
                            <p>
                                <?php 
                                    $str=strlen($filme->filme_descricao);
                                    if ($str > 90) {
                                        echo substr($filme->filme_descricao,0,91).'...';
                                    }else{
                                        echo $filme->filme_descricao;
                                    }
                                ?>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="rule">
                            <p> <?php echo $filme->filme_duracao; ?> &nbsp;&nbsp; <?php echo $filme->filme_ano; ?> &nbsp;&nbsp; 
                            <?php switch ($filme->filme_classificacao) { 
                                case 1: echo '<span style="background: green; padding: 2px 8px; border-radius: 5px;">L</span>';break;
                                case 10: echo '<span style="background: Lightskyblue; padding:  0 5px; color: #fff;  border-radius: 5px;">10</span>'; break;
                                case 12: echo '<span style="background: yellow; color: black; padding:  0 5px; color: #fff;  border-radius: 5px;">12</span>'; break;
                                case 14: echo '<span style="background: orange; padding: 0 5px; color: #fff; border-radius: 5px;">14</span>'; break;
                                case 16: echo '<span style="background: red; padding: 0 5px; color: #fff;  border-radius: 5px;">16</span>'; break;
                                case 18: echo '<span style="background: black; padding: 0 5px; color: #fff;  border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid #fff;">18</span>'; break;
                                } ?>
                                 Classificação Conteúdo</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                var carouselList = $(".filmes_familia");
                checkList();
                carouselList.on('translated.owl.carousel', function(event) {
                    checkList();
                });
                function checkList(){
                    var totalList = $('.filmes_familia .owl-stage .owl-item.active').length;
                    //console.log(totalList);
                    $('.filmes_familia .owl-stage .owl-item').removeClass('firstActiveItem lastActiveItem');
                    $('.filmes_familia .owl-stage .owl-item.active').each(function(index){
                        if (index === 0) {
                            // this is the first one
                            $(this).addClass('firstActiveItem');
                        }
                        if(totalList >= 5){
                            if (index === totalList - 1 && totalList>1) {
                                // this is the last one
                                $(this).addClass('lastActiveItem');
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        </script>
            
        </div>
    </div>

<?php
} ?>
```

O código do javascript que fiz ele funciona pega os proximos filmes dos outros gêneros, porém o problema está sendo exibir esses outros filmes em novos carrosséis:

```
<!-- GENEROS  INIFITE SCROLLING -->
<div class='container-fluid divContainers'></div>

<div class="loader">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
</div>

<script>
    const postsContainer = document.querySelector('.divContainers')
    const loaderContainer = document.querySelector('.loader')
    let page = 1
    

    const getPosts = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(`https://sitedaapi/API/generos?genero=${page}`)
        return response.json()
    }

    const addCarrossel = () => {
        postsContainer.innerHTML = `
        <div class="container-fluid mt-5" style="margin-bottom: 50px !important;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="ne_busness_main_slider_wrapper">
                        <div class="ne_recent_heading_main_wrapper">
                            <h2 style="color: white; font-weight: bold; margin-left: 15px;">Filmes x</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid filme ">
            <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme home-slider nav-outer show-nav-hover nav-image-center filme_${page}" data-owl-options="{
                'loop': false,
                'autoHeight': true,
                'dots': false,
                'nav': false,
                'margin': 15,
                'autoplay': false,
                'responsive': {
                    '1080': {
                        'items': 5  
                    },
                    '640': {
                        'items': 3  
                    },
                    '480': {
                        'items': 2  
                    }
                }
            }
            ">
            
            </div>
        </div>`
    }
    
    const addPostsIntoDOM = async () => {
        const posts = await getPosts()
        const postsTemplate = posts.map(({ slug, img, nome, descricao, duracao, classificacao, ano, genero }) => `
            <div class="list-item">
                <div class="film-list">
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url('perfil/watch?code='); ?>${slug}">
                        <figure class="zoom">
                            <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/imagens/filmes/mini/'); ?>${img}" alt="${nome}" style="width: 100%;">
                        </figure>
                    </a>
                    <div class="actions">
                        <div class="title">
                            <h5 class="text-white">${nome}</h5>
                            </div>
                        <div class="actions-list">
                            <div class="row">
                                <ul>
                                    <div class="col play"><li><a href="<?php echo base_url('perfil/watch?code='); ?>${slug}" data-title="Assistir" class="title-tip"><i class="icon fas fa-play-circle"></i></a></li></div>
                                    
                                    <div class="col thumbs-up"><li><a href="<?php echo base_url('perfil/home/like_add/'); ?>${slug}" data-title="Gostei deste filme" class="title-tip"><i class="icon fas fa-thumbs-up"></i></a></li></div>
                                    <div class="col thumbs-down"><li><a href="<?php echo base_url('perfil/home/deslike_add/'); ?>${slug}" data-title="Não gostei deste filme" class="title-tip"><i class="icon fas fa-thumbs-down"></i></a></li></div>
                                    <div class="col info-circle"><li><a href="<?php echo base_url('perfil/detalhes?code='); ?>${slug}" data-title="Mais Detalhes" class="title-tip"><i class="icon fas fa-info-circle"></i></a></li></div>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="descr">
                            <p>
                                descrição temporária
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="rule">
                        <p> 
                            <span style="background: green; padding: 2px 8px; border-radius: 5px;">L</span>
                            Classificação Conteúdo
                        </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        `).join('')
        document.querySelector('.filme_'+`${page}`).innerHTML += postsTemplate
    }

    addCarrossel()
    addPostsIntoDOM()

    const getNextPosts = () => {
        page++
        addPostsIntoDOM()
    }

    const removeLoader = () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            loaderContainer.classList.remove('show')
            getNextPosts()
        }, 1000)
    }

    const showLoader = () => {
        loaderContainer.classList.add('show')
        removeLoader()
    }

    window.addEventListener('scroll', () =>{
        const { clientHeight, scrollHeight, scrollTop } = document.documentElement
        const isPageBottomAlmostReached = scrollTop + clientHeight >= scrollHeight - 10
        
        if(isPageBottomAlmostReached){
            showLoader()
        }
    })
</script>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

segue um print para entendimento do problema (filmes para toda família está correto porem o filmes x seriam os filmes dos novos carrosséis.

Comment: obs: o filmes para toda família não está no código js ele é fixo na página, carrega junto com o carregamento da pagina normal.